# Elment ui form with PUT request

Tags: php, rest, laravel-5, element-ui

I'm trying to fetch some data in a table, When I send data to create a new item it shows me `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

I'm working with an `element ui` form. I don't know if there's a way to change the request method

This is my form code:

```
   <el-dialog :title="formTitle" :visible.sync="supplierFormVisible">
      <div class="form-container">
        <el-form ref="supplierForm" :model="currentSupplier" label-position="left" label-width="150px" style="max-width: 500px;">
          <el-form-item label="Proveedor" prop="proveedor">
            <el-input v-model="currentSupplier.proveedor" />
          </el-form-item>
          <el-form-item label="Marca" prop="marca">
            <el-input v-model="currentSupplier.marca" />
          </el-form-item>
          <el-form-item label="Contacto" prop="contacto">
            <el-input v-model="currentSupplier.contacto" />
          </el-form-item>
          <el-form-item label="Telefono" prop="telefono">
            <el-input v-model="currentSupplier.telefono" />
          </el-form-item>
          <el-form-item label="Email" prop="email">
            <el-input v-model="currentSupplier.email" />
          </el-form-item>
          <el-form-item label="Pais" prop="pais">
            <el-input v-model="currentSupplier.pais" />
          </el-form-item>
          <el-form-item label="Direccion" prop="direccion">
            <el-input v-model="currentSupplier.direccion" />
          </el-form-item>
          <el-form-item label="Calidad" prop="calidad">
            <el-input v-model="currentSupplier.calidad" />
          </el-form-item>
          <el-form-item label="Pedidos" prop="pedidos">
            <el-input v-model="currentSupplier.pedidos" />
          </el-form-item>
        </el-form>
        <div slot="footer" class="dialog-footer">
          <el-button @click="supplierFormVisible = false">
            Cancel
          </el-button>
          <el-button type="primary" @click="handleSubmit()">
            Confirm
          </el-button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[image: Routes]
[image: error]

UPDATE:

Noticed that the method comes from the api/resources.js file

```
  update(id, resource) {
    return request({
      url: '/' + this.uri + '/' + id,
      method: 'post',
      data: resource,
    });
  }
```

If I change the method to post dont get the error but dont update or add the item to list.

Comment: Can you update your question to clarify things because I don’t know what is your route method you’re trying to reach

Comment: What does the server log say after you change it to POST ?

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't specify the `method` on the form this will be defaulted to `get`. To change this you've to provide the `method` like this:

```
<el-form ref="supplierForm" :model="currentSupplier" label-position="left" label-width="150px" style="max-width: 500px;" method="put">
```

Alternatively you could also solve this with an ajax request, using `fetch` or `axios`

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I applied your solution specifying the method and didn't solve the problem, still getting `405 (Method Not Allowed)`

Comment: What is the request send by the browser?

Comment: PUT request. it should use POST.

Comment: The method comes from the api/resources.js file.
'
  update(id, resource) {
    return request({
      url: '/' + this.uri + '/' + id,
      method: 'post',
      data: resource,
    });
  }
If I change the method to POST dont have the error anymore but it doesnt add or update the list.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem:

You have defined for the route `api/suppliers/{supplier}` only the methods `GET|HEAD|PUT|PATCH|DELETE` but you are trying to call it with the `POST` method. This results in `405`.

Another problem is, that forms don't support `PUT|PATCH|DELETE` Methods, so you have to mock them (laravel calls this [method spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#form-method-spoofing)).

You can add this to your form in a blade template:

```
@method('PUT')
```

or this in a vue template:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```